# Why going through the email action handler in email-link authentication?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Authentication in a web-only application that I'm working on.

In particular, I implemented an email-link authentication flow by taking advantage of the `signInWithEmailLink()` method.

When calling the method, I provide an `actionCodeSettings` object that looks like the following:

```
const actionCodeSettings = {
  handleCodeInApp: true,
  url: 'http://localhost:8080',
};
```

Clicking on the received link takes me to the email action handler (https://my-app.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?continueUrl=xxx&etc) that immediately redirects me to the `continueUrl` parameter value, which is the `url` specified in the `actionCodeSettings` object. Later, on this page, I must call the `signInWithEmailLink()` method to complete the sign-in flow.

My question is, why isn't the email link pointing directly to that `url` instead of the email action handler URL, as (correct me if I'm wrong) the email action handler is not doing any kind of processing here apart from basic redirection?

Answer (score 1):

That page doesn't serve any purpose as far as I know unless Firebase uses it for any internal use. I am not totally sure if this is to prevent losing [email reputation](https://www.sparkpost.com/resources/email-explained/email-sender-reputation/) by adding 3rd party domains in their emails sent by `.firebaseapp.com` domain.

If you wish to skip that page then the best option is to use [Custom Email Handlers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler). You can then send direct link to your page which verifies the `oobCode` (sign in link) and logs user in.

Comment: That would make sense indeed. I'd love to hear from the Firebase team about that.

Comment: I'm not sure whether using a custom email handler would solve the problem though. The link would still point to a URL that's outside my app. Unless of course I use my app's URL as the URL to my custom email action handler. But in this scenario, I'll have to handle ALL the actions from the inside (including sign-in, verifying password resets, etc.) which is kind of cumbersome.

Comment: @ThéophileAvoyne you can customize the domain in custom email handlers. That's the whole point of using them.. you don't need to handle anything much. All you have to do is use `applyActionCode`  method (if using JS)

Comment: I dont quite understand what makes you believe that I said the opposite.

Comment: @ThéophileAvoyne perhaps the issue was user not being sent to your app directly and the comment started with "I'm not sure whether using a custom email handler would solve the problem though"

Comment: We can only have one action handler. It should take care of ALL out-of-band actions. What I just said is that, if I create a custom action handler (with a custom domain being my app domain) to fix the tiny problem I have here, it will also need to handle ALL the other actions (such as verifying password resets). So it will be a lot of code for nothing, as I'm satisfied with the default behaviour in actions other than the one I'm talking about here.

Comment: @ThéophileAvoyne yes, you would have to handle other events yourself then. There doesn't seem to be any way around this atm.